# VB6 Common Dialog Control File Open does not give correct folder on some Windows 7 PCs

Tags: windows, vb6

My VB6 application uses the Common Dialog Control for File Open etc.
The code is working OK on hundreds of PCs.

But I have one customer for which the File Open command displays the wrong folder.
He's running Windows 7.

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
Private Sub mnuFileItem_Click(Index As Integer)
    CommonDialog1.FileName = "" 'workaround for problem with .InitDir (20051010)
    CommonDialog1.InitDir = strDataPath
    ' Set filters
    CommonDialog1.Filter = ApplicationName & " Files (*" & PreProcessorFileExtension & ")|*" & PreProcessorFileExtension        
    ' Set dialog box so error occurs if the dialog box is cancelled '20020418
    CommonDialog1.CancelError = True
    Select Case Index   ' Check index value of selected menu item.
        Case 0  ' If index = 0, the user chose "New"            
            'code omitted here              
        Case 1  ' If index = 1, the user chose "Open..."            
            ' display the File Open dialog
            CommonDialog1.Action = 1                          
            FileName = CommonDialog1.FileName
            OpenCLSFile             
        Case 2 To 3  'If index = 2,  "Save..."  = 3, "Save As..."           
            'code omitted here          
    End Select
End Sub
```

Typically the variable used to define CommonDialog1.InitDir, strDataPath, is set to:

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Mincad Systems\CIRCLY5\data

But for the user that has the problem, the File Open dialog displays:

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Mincad Systems\CIRCLY6\data

I have logs from the user that confirm that CommonDialog1.InitDir =

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Mincad Systems\CIRCLY5\data

before every statement in Sub mnuFileItem_Click.

The user is also using a vb.net version of my application.
In that application the File Open dialog uses the folder:

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Mincad Systems\CIRCLY6\data

Is there some way that the vb.net application resets some property of the Common Dialog Control properties used by the VB6 application?
I have tried replacing the VB6 Common Dialog File Open by using a Win32 API version - but my user still has the same problem.

Regards,
Leigh

Comment: See 3. `lpstrInitialDir
Pointer to a NULL terminated string that can specify the initial directory. The algorithm for selecting the initial directory varies on different platforms.

Comment: Windows 2000/XP:

If lpstrFile contains a path, that path is the initial directory.
Otherwise, lpstrInitialDir specifies the initial directory.
Otherwise, if the application has used an Open or Save As dialog box in the past, the path most recently used is selected as the initial directory. However, if an application is not run for a long time, its saved selected path is discarded.

Comment: If lpstrInitialDir is NULL and the current directory contains any files of the specified filter types, the initial directory is the current directory.
Otherwise, the initial directory is the personal files directory of the current user.
Otherwise, the initial directory is the Desktop folder.

Comment: Thanks, Noodles, for your comments.

Comment: My problem is that my code works on 99.9% of Windows 7 PCs. But why is it not working on the other 0.1% ?

Comment: Just to clarify, *both* the VB 6 and VB.NET application open to the same (wrong) folder? If that's the case, then clearly there is something configured on this machine that is redirecting the desired folder to the new folder.

Comment: Here's an outline of what's going on:

Assume:
the .InitDir for the vb6 app is:  folder_vb6
the .InitDir for the vb.net app is:  folder_vbnet

Comment: The vb.net app Open File dialog always opens the correct folder.

When first installed, the vb6 app Open File dialog opens the correct folder.
And when restarted opens the correct folder.

But if the vb.net app is started and the Open File dialog is used, then app closed, the vb6 app Open File dialog opens folder_vbnet (not the desired one - folder_vb6).
The user can navigate (via the Open File dialog) to the correct folder.
This setting is retained between vb6 app sessions, but is reset to folder_vbnet whenever the vb.net app is run.

Comment: So, in summary, the behaviour is asymmetric - the vb.net app forces it's folder on to the vb6 app, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but maybe this will help someone.   What I found in my case is that if the directory you are setting Initdir to does not exist on that PC, then the current directory is used.